# Does this power law for cartesian products hold and does it come from a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

**Feel free to edit the title of the post or leave a comment if you think that the stated problem is not accurately reflected by the title.**

Let $(X_i, \tau_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of topological spaces.
I want to prove that

$$\prod_{i \in I} \mathbf{2}^{C(X_i,\mathbf{2})} \cong \mathbf{2}^{\biguplus_{i \in I} C(X_i,\mathbf{2})},$$

where $\mathbf{2} = \{0,1\}$ is a discrete topological space, $C(X_i,\mathbf{2})$ is the set of all continuous functions from $X_i$ to $\mathbf{2}$ and $\biguplus$ denotes a disjoint union.

For this isomorphism, I thought it should be sufficient to prove

$$\mathbf{2}^{X \cup Y} \cong \mathbf{2}^X \times \mathbf{2}^Y,$$

for $X \cap Y = \emptyset$. It is easy to find a bijective mapping namely

$$ f \mapsto (f_{|X}, f_{|Y}),$$

but is it continous with respect to the product topology on $2^{X \cup Y}$? And is it a homeomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re working too hard, assuming that by $\mathbf2^{C(X_i,\mathbf2)}$ you mean the ordinary Tikhonov product of $|C(X_i,\mathbf2)|$ copies of $\mathbf2$. Up to homeomorphism that space is determined completely by $|C(X_i,\mathbf2)|$, and $\prod_{i\in I}\mathbf2^{C(X_i,2)}$ has one factor of $\mathbf2$ for each ordered pair $\langle i,f\rangle$ such that $i\in I$ and $f\in C(X_i,\mathbf2)$, so

$$\prod_{i\in I}\mathbf2^{C(X_i,2)}\cong\mathbf2^{\{\langle i,f\rangle:i\in I\text{ and }f\in C(X_i,\mathbf2)\}}=\mathbf2^{\biguplus_{i\in I}C(X_i,\mathbf2)}\;.$$